# Make a Rectangle that covers all the drawn objects in a 2D Array

Tags: c#, arrays, xna, xna-4.0, rectangles

I have a 2D Array of Objects that move synchronously on the screen and I need to detect when they hit the edge of the screen so that they change direction (think Space Invaders). So far, I had it working with a Rectangle pre-defined to be the size and position of the objects in the Array but the Objects can be hit with missiles and are no longer drawn so when all of them on one side are destroyed, the rectangle stays the same size and they change direction too early.

Is there a better way to do what I want to do? This is my code for the functionality at the moment:

(In LoadContent Method)

```
invaderRect = new Rectangle(
    0, 0,
    invadersWide * (invaderImage.Width + 15) - 15,
    invadersHigh * (invaderImage.Height + 15) - 15);
```

(In Update Method)

```
if ((invaderRect.X + invaderRect.Width) >= screenRectangle.Width - 15)
    invadersHitWall = true;
else if (invaderRect.X <= 15)
    invadersHitWall = false;

if (!invadersHitWall)
    invaderRect.X += 2;
else if (invadersHitWall)
    invaderRect.X -= 2;
```

Comment: I've been looking into finding the X value of the very first Object in the Array but I can't find a way to do this. Theres also the problem that it will still get the X value of the first one, even if it's no longer being drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all a matter of organizing your code. You should use an object oriented approach. Create a class that represents your game objects. I would use an abstract base class defining the basic properties and methods. Then derive concrete game objects from this base class. The concrete game objects' constructors have the task to initialize the game objects.

```
public abstract class GameObject
{
    protected BlockType[,] _buildingBlocks; // The 2-d array. Replace "BlockType" 
                                            // by the type you are using.
    protected int _x0, _y0; // Indexes of the first non empty block.
    protected int _x1, _y1; // Indexes of the last  non empty block + 1.

    // Pixel coordinates of upper left corner of the intact game object.
    public Point Location { get; set; }

    // Represents the current position and size of the possibly diminished
    // game object in pixels.
    public Rectangle BoundingBox
    { 
        get {
            return new Rectangle(
                Location.X + BlockSize * _x0,
                Location.Y + BlockSize * _y0,
                BlockSize * (_x1 - _x0),
                BlockSize * (_y1 - _y0)
            );
        } 
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics g, int x, int x)
    {
        for (int i = _x0; i < _x1; i++) {
            for (int j = _y0; j < _y1; j++) {
                BlockType block = _buildingBlocks[i, j];
                if (block != null) {
                    // Replace by the appropriate drawing methods for XNA.
                    g.FillRectangle(block.Brush,
                                    x + BlockSize * i, y + BlockSize * j,
                                    BlockSize, BlockSize);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Call this after changes have been made to the arrray which may affect the
    // apparent size of the game object, e.g. after the object was hit by a bomb.
    protected void CalculateBounds()
    {
        _x0 = _buildingBlocks.GetLength(0);
        _y0 = _buildingBlocks.GetLength(1);
        _x1 = 0;
        _y1 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _buildingBlocks.GetLength(0); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < _buildingBlocks.GetLength(1); j++) {
                if (buildingBlocks[i, j] != null) {
                   _x0 = Math.Min(_x0, i);
                   _y0 = Math.Min(_y0, j);
                   _x1 = Math.Max(_x1, i + 1);
                   _y1 = Math.Max(_y1, j + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void DestroyBlocksAt(IEnumerable<Point> points)
    {
        //TODO: destroy hit blocks.

        CalculateBounds();
    }
}
```

After an object has been hit by a bomb, call `CalculateBounds();` in order to recalculate the real size of the object. The idea is that instead of using `invaderRect` you would be using the `BoundingBox` property that reflects the real extents of the gaming object. `BoundingBox` takes into account the position of the game object on the screen (`Location`) and the position within the array (`_x0`, `_x1`, `_y0`, `_y1`).

This is a raw sketch. You may have to refine it and adapt it to your current logic.  Don't use magical numbers like `15`. Define constants like `public const int BlockSize = 15;`. This makes it easier to change the numbers later and also to understand the code.

Here is an example of an invader class

```
public class Invader : GameObject
{
    private const int WIDTH = 10, HEIGHT = 7; // Width and height of invader in blocks.

    public Invader()
    {
        _buildingBlocks = new BlockType[WIDTH, HEIGHT];
        _x1 = WIDTH;
        _y1 = HEIGHT;
        _buildingBlocks[0, 0] = ...
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

As I understood your post, every movable “thing” is stored in its own 2D array storing the 15 x 15 pixel  blocks it is made of. `GameObject` is the base class of all the visible movable things, like invaders, space ships, bombs and so on and is a wrapper around the 2D arrays (named `_buildingBlocks` in my code examples). It adds the logic needed to determine the real bounds of objects after they have been hit by bombs. `CalculateBounds` recalculates the position and size of the remaining object after a bomb hit within the 2D array (of course you must call it every time the shape of the objects changes). `BoundingBox` moves these internal 2D array bounds (stored in `_x0`, `_x1`, `_y0` and `_y1`) to real screen positions (stored in the `Location` property) by multiplying with the block size (the 15 pixels) and adding the screen location.

For every game object type (i.e. movable shape type) you have to derive a class (e.g. a class `Invader` for invaders). Then create an invader object with `Invader invader = new Invader();` for every single invader. `GameObject` is not the main class. The main class includes the game loop and game logic. It creates game objects and calculates their new positions (stored in the `Location` property) as they move around. Instead of working with `invaderRect` the wall-hitting logic would now work with `BoundingBox` which returns the real size and positions of the objects.

```
Rectangle invaderBounds = invader.BoundingBox;
bool isLeftWallHit = invaderBounds.Left <= 0;
bool isRightWallHit = invaderBounds.Right >= screenRectangle.Width;
bool isUpperWallHit = invaderBounds.Top <= 0;
bool isLowerWallHit = invaderBounds.Bottom >= screenRectangle.Height;
```

Comment: This is my first game and it's very important that I complete it, but this is really confusing. Also, my Game Objects are all classes being created as needed in the main class.

Comment: g.FillRectangle is creating errors. I also don't understand the content of your Draw method. And the BoundingBox doesn't seem to be updated though I may not understand how it works if its defined outside of other Methods

Comment: The code is not complete. In a concrete class you would initialize the 2-d array and `x1` (= width of array), `y1` (= height of array) in the constructor. Each time a change to the 2-d array is made, e.g. after a bomb partially destroyed an object, you would call `CalculateBounds`. Probably the error occurs because these values were not initialized. `BoundingBox` depends on the values calculated by `CalculateBounds` and `Location`.

Comment: The `GameObject` class wouldn't be my main class, would it? And is this `_buildingBlocks` array being defined and the invaders added in `Invader` class? Sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding it all... >.<

Comment: I added an update explaining the things a bit more in detail.

Comment: Okay, that helps quite a bit. But what is `BlockType` and where do I initialize it? And would I be creating a new array and filling it with invaders in the main class?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `Graphics` type or class in existance

Comment: `System.Drawing.Graphics` is the object type passed to the `Paint` methods in WinForms applications. If you are using another technology (like XNA) you will have to adapt the code accordingly. Just keep the way of drawing you used until now. I'm just trying to show you how you can organize your code. You will have to adapt the details of my examples to your needs.

Comment: So should I replace `g.FillRectangle...` with the invader's texture etc? I'll get it eventually.. New to this.
And I still don't understand `BlockType`. I am using XNA

Comment: You did not show us the type of your 2D-array. Therefore I just used the generic name `BlockType`. Replace `BlockType` by the type you are using for your 2D-array! Does you array contain textures or texture numbers or something else? This is meant by `BlockType`.

Comment: The array contains invaders of type Invader which is made of a Texture2D and a Rectangle. But I solved my problem and did it another way.. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'll definitely make use of this way of organizing my code in the future.

Comment: I was assuming that an invader was made by a lot of (`Texture2D`)textue blocks stored in the 2D arrays (one array for each inavder), so that a bomb would destroy some of the textures while leaving others intact and thus, would change the shape of the invader.

Comment: The game is a Space Invaders clone